# How to write JUnit Testing for methods receives a String and return LocalDate?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have this method that I want to test it with JUnit. It converts String into LocalDate.

```
public static LocalDate convertDate(String aDate) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(aDate, formatter);

        return localDate;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JUnit tutorial for learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425616/junit-tutorial-for-learning)

Answer (score 3):

Such code is easy to unit test: you can invoke that method with a specific string, then you check that the method returns a LocalDate that matches your expectations.

Comment: can you give me like an example of how it should look like?

Answer (score 2):

Your test method could look something like this:

```
@org.junit.Test
public void test() {
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
    LocalDate result = classUnderTest.convertDate("22-04-2019");
    assertEquals(result.getDayOfMonth(), 22);
    assertEquals(result.getMonth(), Month.APRIL);
    assertEquals(result.getYear(), 2019);
}
```

A couple of comments about it:

1. I use an instance of the ClassUnderTest. Generally I am not a fan of using static methods when it isn't necessary. Instance methods are easier to mock in tests that depend on the class in question.
2. Also I use the date format "dd-MM-yyyy" in my case. You can change the asserts as you need them.

Comment: I prefer to use assertThat and a hamcrest matcher, but your example should do for a newbie!